# Should Eclipse Product Configuration Files be Edited in the workspace .metadata folder?

Tags: eclipse, design-patterns, plugins, configuration

I've walked into a new project where they use Eclipse but don't completely "get it," and I want to start cleaning up some of the infrastructure so that it is more reasonable.

Some of the plugins (2 or 3) have a config.xml file in them which points to various servers that are configured for the end customer. For our testing, we have to edit the server addresses. These config files are read in and edited from the workspace's .metadata->.plugins file. This has the ill effect of causing the program to not run properly the first time that it is launched (because the plugins need to be copied into the metadata area).

I have never seen this done in the past. is this a generally accepted practice in Eclipse or is it something that I should dig my heels in and insist we change to a different pattern (such as using the ResourceBundle package).

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do dig your heals in here; this is definitely *not* an accepted practice. Nothing should directly touch anything inside of the `.metadata` folder in the workspace. Use another means to find your configuration file, accessing them as a resource is perfectly fine.